# Apache : mod_rewrite : Redirect URL from abc.com to abc.com/xyz without changing the URL in browser

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, mod-alias

I have tried different things like below but no luck  :

1. `Redirect "/" "REPLACE WITH YOUR COMPLETE URL"` in virtual host.
2. `Redirect permanent "/one" "Replace with your complete URL"` in virtual host.
3. Outside Virtual Host:

   ```
   <Location "/">
   Redirect permanent "REPLACE WITH YOUR COMPLETE URL"
   </Location>
   ```

But in all the cases, URL in the browser changes to the replaced URL, which we don't want.

Actual values :
`/` to be redirected to `/olyweb`

How would I use URL Masking or something which can redirect internally but don't reflect on browser.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will always display the URL it is talking to. It cannot be fooled.

You can only do what you want by letting your Apache httpd act as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). You cannot do it with things like `mod_rewrite`.

In a reverse proxy the httpd will sit *in front of* your target web server. All communication to and from your target web server will travel *through* the httpd. Therefore you can effectively access your target web server via an alternative URL. Unlike with HTTP Redirect solutions your browser will in the reverse proxy scenario never actually know that all content comes from the target web server. Your browser never communicates with the target web server, it communicates with your httpd process.

Comment: Tried doing that but getting 502.